# PHP ini_set max_execution_time nog working properly?

Tags: php, execution-time, ini-set

To monitor the `max_execution_time` of a particular script, I use

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds = 10 minutes`

at the top of my script. However, when I build a logging of the same file it returns me the following:

```
25-09-2017 23:08:01|STARTED
25-09-2017 23:09:01|ALREADY RUNNING
25-09-2017 23:10:01|ALREADY RUNNING
...................|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 01:09:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 01:10:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 01:11:01|STARTED
26-09-2017 01:12:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 01:13:01|ALREADY RUNNING
...................|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 03:10:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 03:11:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 03:12:01|STARTED
26-09-2017 03:13:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 03:14:02|ALREADY RUNNING
...................|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 05:09:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 05:10:02|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 05:11:01|STARTED
26-09-2017 05:12:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 05:13:02|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 05:14:01|ALREADY RUNNING
...................|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 07:14:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 07:15:01|ALREADY RUNNING
26-09-2017 07:16:01|STARTED
```

The `...................|ALREADY RUNNING` represents multiple messages repeating every minute in between.

What am I doing wrong, since the interval is not 10 minutes by far?

***EDIT:***

The while loop I have:

```
while (true) {
    //DO PROCESSING WHEN FILES ARE PRESENT
    Sleep(1);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked what your actual timeout limit is with phpinfo(), and loading the page with a browser?

If you're running php-fpm and nginx or anything out the old "Apache and PHP" confines, the actual time limits might be set, and override PHP's own php.ini, else where.

Comment: @DocWeird, I run the script with a cronjob. The phpinfo states that the max. execution time is set on 30 for both the local and master value.

Comment: Are you using sleep -command in the script? IIRC using sleep does not increase the execution time.

Comment: @DocWeird, yes I have a while(true) loop with a sleep of 1 second at the end of the loop. So, how can I overcome this? I use the Sleep to prevent CPU from rising to 100% when the while loop has nothing to perform (it processes files when present). See the edit in my question for the while loop example

Comment: Hmm... How about using two scripts? A main script that will call the script which processes files *and* sleeps. That way the main script should still time out while the called script will happily go about sleeping without concerns about execution times.

Comment: @DocWeird, to check your statement I decreased the max execution time to 2 minutes and removed the sleep. It now restarts every 2 minutes as expected. Thanks for your great answer regarding the sleep not counting towards the Max Execution time. The idea of multiple scripts might be a great idea, however it will be eating resources, since I have to start a new process for each file to process? Sometimes I receive over 100 files at once to process immediately, which results in 100 new commands triggering new instances of the processing script meaning that 100 processing script will start?

Answer (score 1):

Just check execution time manually.

```
$max_exec_time = 600;

$start_time = time();
while (true) {
  do_something();
  sleep(1);
  if (time() - $start_time > $max_exec_time) {
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is actually a great idea! Thanks..! Any disadvantages known for this approach to consider?

Comment: Only one I can think of is that it won't exit until do_something() is completed. So you should probably set max_execution_time too, just in case.